# Can I add the pattern attribute to textarea?

Tags: html

I know that the textarea doesn't support the functionality of pattern, however if I set the pattern variable in html, its still present in the browser.

So I have to execute the pattern verification in js anyways, but is it OK for me to store the pattern in the pattern attribute? As opposed to data-pattern or something, for consistency with the input elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom attribute is suppose to have the `data-` prefix, so I recommend to use that or you could ran into issues when validating your code.

And what happens if such an attribute suddenly become a standard attribute?

More to read:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#data-*
- https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Answer (score 1):

You should use `data-*` attributes for extra attributes and since `textarea` tag does not support the `pattern` attribute then adding it like adding `value` to div.

Hope this helps.